# Changing the View Without Navigating

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UINavigationController` and a tab bar in it.

when a button is clicked I want the view to change without changing away from the `UINavigationController` or the `TabBarController`.

I tried using a `ModalViewController` but it hides tab bar and navigation bar.

How can I achieve this? Should I create a new `ViewController`?

Also What am I supposed to do if I want that view to appear only on some part of the screen?

Comment: add subview to your viewController's view

Comment: [self.view addSubview:yourView];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create another view in the same class and then add it to your viewController by writing

> [self.view addSubview:newView];

and make it hide by

> newView.hidden = YES;

and show it when user taps on button by

> newView.hidden = NO;

**EDIT:** For view to appear only on some part of the screen.
set the frame of the newView as

> newView.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,300,50);//do according to your needs

Comment: What am i supposed to do if i want that view to appear only at some part of the screen??

Comment: adjust the frame to cover only part of the screen. [bla setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)] will cover 100 x 100 px of the screen only.

Comment: @futureelite7 is absolute correct, I just edited my answer for completing the answer of your question.